# Is it possible to create my own crontab special string?

Tags: linux, cron

The cron daemon includes eight special strings, starting with "@" : `@reboot`, `@yearly` etc... (`man 5 crontab`). And I would like to create my own: `@five_minutes = */5 * * * *`.

But is there a way to create new special strings in crontab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the syntax does not allow anything like this.

Perhaps you could write a simple parser for your format, and generate your actual `crontab` from that.

```
sed 's%^@five_minutes%*/5 * * * *%' crontab.in | crontab -
```

For this particular simple use case, learning the proper syntax seems like a much simpler and more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, this is a simple example, my question may have more sense with "@never = 2 2 31 2 2" for example (used in a code which relies on the crontab). In that case, @never would be better than the proper syntax.

Comment: You can use comments in your crontab to explain why you use a specific peculiar pattern like that. Not a solution, but a workaround.